# returning string matching regular expression

Tags: python, regex, search, text, return

I have a textfile with lines of which I want to extract one line that matches a certain pattern. Can I search for that line with a regular expression and return it, to work with it afterwards? Is there a more elegant way than

```
for lines in file:
    if re.match(targetregex,line)!=None:
        print line
```

Something like:

```
print re.matchingline(targetregex,file.read())
```

Comment: What do you expect to print if there is no match?

Comment: Did I write it down wrong? I have a look. But I want to return /print it if there IS a match. Sorry but I don't see the mistake. Help me. !=None means that if there is a match it will be printed, right?

Comment: If you really want a comparison with `None`, you should use `is not None` instead of `!= None` (although in many cases, including this one, you're not going to have a non-None falsy value anyway, so skip the check and use the boolean value of the expression directly)

Comment: I just asked the question below the accepted answer: My misunderstanding was, that an if-condition has to be True to lead to the consequence. But obviously it's sufficient if it's not False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension, like this

```
print [line for line in file  if re.match(targetregex, line)]
```

It will return you the list of lines which match the regular expression.

Comment: But now tell me something about the how if conditions work (I could also ask this as a separate question?): re.match(targetregex, line) does not return True. Why will if re.match... enter the consequence of the if condition? I thought it has to be if (condition==True): Consequence

Comment: Anything which is not a non-falsy value in python's if will return true. Read more about it here http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Answer (score 1):

You could always just write your own function to do the job.

```
def matchingline(regex, file):
    compiled = re.compile(regex)
    for line in file:
        if compiled.match(line):
            return line

print(matchingline(targetregex, file))
```

Comment: I am not sure if only the first one is wanted. So a generator might be the better choice. Just `yield` instead of `return`...

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted an array [numpy.fromregex](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromregex.html) seems elegant enough.